# Linking to a custom Facebook tab from another using target="_blank" works perfect, anything else doesn't

Tags: html, facebook, target

I have a couple of custom tabs I have developed for a Facebook page and I want to link one to another.

I use `target="_blank"` in the link attributes it works perfectly, however I want the link to open in the same window so if I remove the target attribute I get a blank screen in Firefox and nothing happens at all in Chrome.

However, if I shift+click in Chrome it again works perfectly.

```
<p><a href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/PAGE_NAME/PAGE_ID?v=app_APP_ID" title="blah"><img src="../images/frame1b.jpg" alt="blah" style="border: 0 none;" /></a></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `target="_parent"` that should open it in the same browser tab.

Comment: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaah I don't believe it was as simple as that.... atleast the answer is here for anyone else who has this problem. Thank you very much Bjorn, you have saved me a lot of stress!